# hide div's with different values in id name

Tags: jquery

I have many divs that are name such as:

```
<div store_id="1"></div>
<div store_id="2"></div>
<div store_id="3"></div>
<div store_id="4"></div>
```

I am trying to hide them without specifically defining the value by doing this:

```
    $('div[store_id=' + this.value + ']').hide();
```

I have a option variable that has the same value as the stor_id div's and also tried:

```
$('div[store_id=' + option.attr("value") + ']').hide();
```

but neither of them are found when I check them on chrome source code debugger or working when I plug them in. what am I doing wrong?

option comes from :

```
var option = $("#idea_store_ids :nth-child("+(parseInt(value)+1)+")");


decentness to #idea_store_ids:

<select id="idea_store_ids" name="idea[store_ids][]" multiple="multiple" style="display: 
none;">

<option value="103">

    4 Wheeling Shirts-To-Go

</option>
<option value="79" selected="selected"> … </option>
<option value="63"> … </option>
<option value="2" selected="selected"> … </option>
<option value="19"> … </option>
<option value="75"> … </option>
<option value="122"> … </option>
<option value="18"> … </option>
```

entire js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#idea_store_ids').chosen().change(function(){
    var doai = $(".search-choice-close").map(function(){
      return $(this).attr("data-option-array-index");}
  ).get();
  $.each(doai , function(index, value) { 
    var option = $("#idea_store_ids :nth-child("+(parseInt(value)+1)+")");


  });
   });
});

$("div[store_id=' + value + ']").hide();
```

Comment: What is `this.value` or `option.attr('value')` returning for you?

Comment: What is `this` and `option` ? were do you get them from?

Comment: Works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/JTKgS/ looks like either `this.value` is wrong or `option.attr("value")` is wrong. since you haven't shown what those things actually reference, we can't help you without further input.

Comment: Where did you get `this.value` from?

Comment: i added where option comes from

Comment: Please add more code. Maybe this is clear for you, but for us we need to see more code to understand your idea.

Comment: Even given your additional code, i have no way of knowing if `var option = $("#idea_store_ids :nth-child("+(parseInt(value)+1)+")");` actually selects an option.

Comment: Why aren't you using data attributes???

Answer (score 1):

You can hide `<div>`s. Try this:

```
<div store_id="1"></div>
<div store_id="2"></div>
<div store_id="3"></div>
<div store_id="4"></div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var allDivs = $("div").length;
    for(var x =0; x <  allDivs; x++){
        var element = $("div").attr("store_id",x);
         $(element).hide();
    }                   
});
```